# Omitting duplicates from a list in jquery

Tags: jquery

Using jquery, given the following list:

```
<div>cat</div>
<div>dog</div>
<div>horse</div>
<div>cat</div>
<div>goat</div>
<div>mouse</div>
```

How do we loop through them and omit -- `hide()` or `remove()` -- duplicates, ie. "cat" ?

Answer (score 0):

Given,

```
<div class="my-list">
 <div>cat</div>
 <div>dog</div>
 <div>horse</div>
 <div>cat</div>
 <div>goat</div>
 <div>mouse</div>
</div>
```

Then you can:

```
const $list = $('.my-list');
const showed = [];
$list.find('div').each(function() {
   if ( $.inArray($(this).text(), showed) === -1 ) {
      showed.push($(this).text());
   } else {
      $(this).hide();  // or .remove()
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var x = $('div');
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    for(var j = i+1; j < x.length; j++) {
    if($(x[i]).html() === $(x[j]).html()) {
        $(x[i]).addClass('de');
    }
  }
}
```

and this CSS

```
.de {
  display: none;
 }
```